# How do I change the name of an approved, but not released app in the app store and on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app, which is approved, but not released to the app store yet.

How can I change the name under which it is displayed in the app store and on the device?

Comment: You can't change either of these things without uploading an updated app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name that appears on the device it's not the same with the name on the app store. You can rename the app from the `<ProjectName>-Info.plist` file and update the app.

Then, you can change the app store name of the app too. *(Not 100% sure if update is absolutely needed at this point.)*

Comment: I assume the key in the -Info.plist file is "Bundle Name"? Or "Bundle Display Name"? or both?

Comment: And what is the "Bundle Name" good for? Where is it displayed?

Comment: And the Bundle Identifier? If I had to change this, I will have to recreate all profiles, certificates, entitlements? Can I have a Bundle Identifier which is different from Bundle Name/Bundle Display Name?

Comment: Will I have to change the name of the app ID in the Developer Portal?